# CSS flip animation flickering in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions

I have created a flip board animation with CSS transitions, and it works fine in Chrome/Firefox/Edge, but in Safari it flickers a lot during the transition, but the final state is correct.

I thought it might be a problem with the z-index in the transitions, but when removing those the flickering is still there.
I have autoprefixer on so I don't think it's an issue with backface-visibility.

If you look at this codepen in both Chrome and Safari, you can see the how it's supposed to be in Chrome, and the flickering issue in Safari.
https://codepen.io/joel-udd/pen/QWpEQMM

```
<div class="board board-1">
  <div class="row-1">
    <div class="letter-wrapper">
      <div class="behind-letter">
        <div class="behind bottom"><span>F</span></div>
        <div class="behind top">I</div>
      </div>
      <div class="letter">
        <div class="flip front">H</div>
        <div class="flip back"><span>I</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="letter">
        <div class="flip front">G</div>
        <div class="flip back"><span>H</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="letter">
        <div class="flip front">F</div>
        <div class="flip back"><span>G</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.board {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000px;

    .letter-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative; 
        width: 11vw;
        margin-left: 2px;
        height: 14vw;

        .flip, .behind {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 14vw;
            
            span {
                display: inline-block;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
            }
        }

        .letter {
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 2px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 7vw;
            transform: rotateX(0);
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-origin: bottom center;

            .flip {
                height: 100%;
                backface-visibility: hidden;
            
                &.back {
                    transform: rotateX(180deg);
                }
            }

            &:nth-child(2) {
                z-index: 10;
            }
            &:nth-child(3) {
                z-index: 20;
            }
            &:nth-child(4) {
                z-index: 30;
            }
        }

        .behind-letter {
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 5;
        
            .behind {
                height: 50%;
        
                &.bottom {
                    top: calc(50% + 2px);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &.active {
        .row-1 {
            .letter-wrapper {
              .letter {
                transform: rotateX(-180deg);
                
                &:nth-child(2) {
                  z-index: 50;
                  transition: transform .5s .5s, z-index 0s .6s;
                }
                
                &:nth-child(3) {
                  z-index: 40;
                  transition: transform .5s .3s, z-index 0s .4s;
                }
                
                &:nth-child(4) {
                  transition: transform .5s .1s;
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you using SCSS? I am asking this because you have mentioned CSS instead of it

Comment: @michael.grigoryan Yes, I am using SCSS. Sorry if that was unclear.